# Xamarin.Forms: can grid cell include several labels?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

One of the grid cells looks like this:

```
<Label Text="{Binding Address1}" FontSize="12" TextColor="Black" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"/>
```

This displays `Address1` which is correct.

But instead of just showing `Address1`, I would like to display `Address1`, `City`, `St`, each with a different `FontSize`.

Can this be done without altering the number of rows and columns in the grid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to place a StackLayout at the Grid row|column and then separately format each element within it:

```
<Grid....
    ~~~
    <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
        <Label Text="{Binding Address1}" FontSize="12" TextColor="Black" />
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" >
            <Label Text="{Binding City}" FontSize="10" TextColor="Black" />
            <Label Text="{Binding St}" FontSize="10" TextColor="Black" />
        </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout>
    ~~~
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you would use:

```
<StackLayout Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
  <Label Text="l1"/>
  <Label Text="l2"/>
  <Label Text="l3"/>
</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use other layouts such as StackLayout inside of your Grid as others suggested but you can also put multiple Views inside a Grid cell by setting the same `Grid.Row` and `Grid.Column` for them and by setting `HorizontalOptions` and `VerticalOptions` of views inside the Grid you can choose each view position.

For Example:

```
<Grid....
    ~~~
    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Start" Text="{Binding Address1}" FontSize="12" TextColor="Black" />
    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="End" Text="{Binding City}" FontSize="10" TextColor="Black" />
    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalOptions="End" Text="{Binding St}" FontSize="10" TextColor="Black" />
    ~~~
</Grid>
```